# C - Filling a structure from a text file

Tags: c, structure

I have a text file filled with some numbers that I would like to read.

My text file looks like this.

```
1  2  3  5  0

2  5  8  5  0

7  8  6  9  0
```

I would like to read this text file into this structure:

```
struct numbers num[]
```

My struct is defined like this:

```
struct numbers {
       int totalnumbers;
};
```

The first time this would go into the structure:

```
1  2  3  5  0
```

And th second time:

```
2  5  8  5  0
```

And so on unitl the end of the file.

Thank very much in advance for any help.

Comment: How is the structure defined ? What have you tried ?

Comment: I havent tried anything so far :S, Iam very new in C and was looking for advice.

Comment: My structre has one member and it is totalnumbers.

Comment: @Anders That doesn't make any sense. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Anders, the way it is defined a two-dimensional array seems more appropriate.  To use an array of structs, each element within the struct needs to have a name.  Do you have any preferences or do you need to see an example in which arbitrary names are chosen?  (It's tagged homework so such names may have been specified in the assignment....)

Comment: @cnicutar - All I would like to do is read each line of numbers and put them in the struct numbers num[], then if possible for the each line of code get the total amout of numbers, 1+2+4+5 and so on..

Comment: @Anders: You still haven't explained how the struct is/should be defined exactly. Using an array of structs to read only numbers seems like a strange idea. Do you have any code so far you could show us?

Comment: @iceaway - The reason I want to read the numbers using array of struct is the assignment asks for is :S. and please se my updated question for the struct definition.

Comment: @Anders: I think the best advice is the answer by Binary Worrier below. Try to use his hints to come up with an idea for something that could work. It won't be much help for you if we just provide you with a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My *advice* is to refer to your course notes/textbook and start writing code.
Honestly you will learn nothing by taking a completed program from the answers here.

- Start by writing a program to open the file and write the first line
  in the file to the console (*hint* `fopen` and `fgets` . . . *I think, it's been a while*).
- Then put in a loop to write each line to the console.
- Then figure out how to split the line into individual numbers (*hint*
  `strtok`)
- Then figure out how to convert the numbers from the file (which are
  strings) to integers (*hint* prefer `strtol` over `atoi`)
- Then declare a **large** array and stick the numbers into it.

Programming is all about divide & conquer, which is really just solving the little problems one at a time until the big problems are solved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tip: strtoul is much better than atoi, there is virtually no reasons to use atoi.

Comment: @hlovdal: I stand corrected, my `C` knowledge is old . . . _oh so very old_

Comment: @hlovdal: strtol is better than strtoul to replace atoi, because it supports neg. integers

Answer (score 0):

you could use strtok(input, " \n") and then convert the strings you get to numbers using atoi()

Answer (score 0):

You could use scanf("%i", ) for each value you want to read.
It's a bit dangerous because its easy to crash the program and because it's difficult to find out how much records are there in the file (The latter problem may be avoided if the first value in the file tells you the number of lines with meaningful content)

Another possibility is to read a line using fgets() (not gets()), and to tokenize it either with strtok() or a custom loop which parses the line (not recommended, it's messy to write, produces spaghetti code and is vulnerable to bugs).